# File transfer support in asterisk

Tags: android, asterisk, file-transfer, sdp

I just set up an asterisk server on my debian box.
After some fighting with asterisk's config, I finally succeeded to make two android phones to call each other. Even video call is working ! So it's pretty cool.
My configuration is really basic. I'm using imsDroid softphone on the android phones.
Now, I need to be able to do file transfer (file sharing) between those two phones. 
imsDroid have this built-in capability.
But when I try to send a file (in this case, an image), I get this error on asterisk:

```
WARNING[19405]: chan_sip.c:9084 process_sdp: Unsupported SDP media type in offer: message 34515 TCP/MSRP *
WARNING[19405]: chan_sip.c:9177 process_sdp: Failing due to no acceptable offer found
```

Using asterisk debug, I found that SIP server replies a `488 Not acceptable here` when a softphone tries to send image. Full debug log: http://pastebin.com/mxc04i2T

I've been searching all day on google and forums, I've read many docs but I can't find anything to resolve this issue.
I get the same error when trying to send a txt file or binary file.
I bet I'm missing something.
**Do I need to add a codec for this to work ? How can I debug this ? Does asterisk even support file transfer (via msrp or any other protocol) ?**
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need do

```
asterisk -r
sip set debug on
```

and see what it offer.

Actualy asterisk have no functionality like described, but it still can be working if app use sip message or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Softphone offers a `message 34515 TCP/MSRP *`. I edited the question with the full asterisk debug log. Any ideas?

Comment: current asterisk not support tcp rtp streams of described types(actualy not support any tcp). You can use opensips/kamailio as proxy for such system(complexity medium, require some special knowledge) or patch asterisk(complexity high, require alot of special knowledge). No, you can't do anything without patching or changing your system architecture.

Comment: Asterisk does not support RTP TCP. That much is true. Other than that, this answer is wrong on a lot of levels.
1) Both chan_sip and chan_pjsip support SIP signalling over TCP.
2) Using Kamailio to get TCP is using a missile launcher to shoot a mosquito.
3) Patching Asterisk does not require changing your system architecture.

Comment: Sure signaling via tcp is supported. RTP via tcp was never supported,in dump requested tcp rtp,check dump. IF you use kamailio, you can do autonegotiation between such app and it will work ok. i said "patching OR change". Please read carefully something you say compleatly wrong.